# BrowserId login request is called right at document loading

Tags: javascript, browserid

My browserId login code is almost verbatim from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Quick_Setup?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=BrowserID%2FQuick_Setup#Step_3.3A_Watch_for_login_and_logout_actions). But when I open the Route, the request is sent automatically, no matter if `loggedInEmail` is set or anything else, and it results in an eternal refresh loop. My Javascript code is, when [generated](https://gist.github.com/842c678aa9ff76428069):

```
navigator.id.watch({
    'loggedInEmail': null,
    'onlogin': (function (jmId_1_0) {
        $.ajax({
            'data': {
                'assertion': jmId_1_0
            },
            'error': (function (jmId_1_1, jmId_1_2, jmId_1_3) {
                alert(("login failure" + jmId_1_1));
            }),
            'success': (function (jmId_1_4, jmId_1_5, jmId_1_6) {
                console.log(jmId_1_4);
            }),
            'type': "POST",
            'url': "\/login"
        });
    }),
    'onlogout': (function () {
        $.ajax({
            'error': (function (jmId_1_7, jmId_1_8, jmId_1_9) {
                alert(("logout failure" + jmId_1_7));
            }),
            'success': (function (jmId_1_10, jmId_1_11, jmId_1_12) {
                window.location.reload();
            }),
            'type': "POST",
            'url': "\/logout"
        });
    })
});
$((function () {
    $("#loginBtn").click((function (jmId_1_13) {
        jmId_1_13.preventDefault();
        navigator.id.request();
        return false;
    }));
}));
```

The `onlogin` functions is always called, no matter if the user clicked the button. It must be somewhere in browserId itself, or I did something fundamentally wrong.

Full template code can be found [here](https://github.com/scan/neighr/blob/master/src/Template.hs#L38).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I too have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this problem was caused from an incorrect setting of `loggedInEmail`.